# Salt can't parse files any more: Requisite declaration... is not formed as a single key dictionary

Tags: salt-stack

About two-month-old **`sls`** files are working no more. I've tried to put the minimal example below:

**`salt 'myserver.internal' state.highstate`** gave:

```
myserver.internal:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    Requisite declaration dhparam in SLS nginx is not formed as a single key dictionary

----------
    Requisite declaration /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.conf in SLS nginx is not formed as a single key dictionary
ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code
```

with the following `nginx.sls`:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.conf:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.conf
    - source: salt://nginx-myapp.conf.jinja
    - template: jinja
    - require:
      - dhparam

dhparam:
  cmd:
    - run
    - name: "mkdir -p /etc/nginx/ssl/; openssl dhparam -out /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem 2048"
    - unless: ls /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem
```

And there are tens of those errors when I run the whole configuration. Am I missing something? Maybe, some crucial dependency not installed/updated/broken? yamllint did not find any problems in my `SLS` files. Same files worked well on another server two months ago.

Versions:

salt-master                      2016.11.6+ds-1

salt-minion                      2015.8.8+ds-1

The system is `Ubuntu Xenial 16.04.2 LTS` on both master and minion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the version of the minion. While I added repo key for saltstack, I forgot to add

```
deb http://repo.saltstack.com/apt/ubuntu/16.04/amd64/latest xenial main
```

to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/saltstack.list` and run `apt update` before installing salt-minion.

When I corrected that, files started to work again.

Comment: Before 2016.3.0, the requisites required to specify the module used, not just the id. In your case, it would have been: `cmd: dhparam`. https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#omitting-state-module-in-requisites